# C# Generic tables

Tags: c#, generics

I have multiple classes that have a fled called "rows" however the rows field is of a different class type for each table.

So in the below example I have a fish table and a bird table. The table class is essentially the same but the rows field is of a specific class type making it easy for someone to reference properties on that object.

XXX.rows[0].canfly would be easy to reference if it's a bird.

So now I'm trying to write a generic method that can fetch multiple instances of FishTable or BirdTable .. do some magic, merge them into one table of that type and return the result. All the method needs to know is what type of table we're talking about and a few other basic parameters.

I know I'm approaching this incorrectly but I can quite tell where I'm falling down.

9 out of 10 times I run into something like this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0311  The type 'GenericTest.FishTable<GenericTest.fish>' cannot be 
used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Tester.test<T>()'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 
'GenericTest.FishTable<GenericTest.fish>' to 
'GenericTest.ITable<GenericTest.FishTable<GenericTest.fish>>'.  GenericTest  
C:\Users\WarrickF\source\repos\EOSTools\GenericTest\Program.cs  14  Active
```

I know I need to go an really understand Generics as I really no have business writing Generics like this without a descent understanding but .. well this is a real example I'm working through.

```
interface ITable<T>
{
    List<T> rows { get; set; }
}




public class BirdTable<T> : ITable<T>
{
    public List<T> rows { get; set; }
}

public class FishTable<T> : ITable<T>
{
    public List<T> rows { get; set; }
}


public abstract class animal {
    public int eyeCount;
}

public class bird : animal
{
    public int featherCount;
    public bool canFly;
}

public class fish : animal
{
    public int numberOfFins;
    public bool depth;
}
```

Comment: You also need to share the code which has the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chetan Ranpariya's comment is right on.  I can try to help a bit anyway, but it's partly guesswork.  You want to merge multiple tables, with rows of type `T`, but the error message seems to indicate that your code somewhere expects individual `T`s instead.

```
There is no implicit reference conversion from 
'GenericTest.FishTable<GenericTest.fish>' to 
'GenericTest.ITable<GenericTest.FishTable<GenericTest.fish>>'.
```

There are rather more problems here, though.  Your interface is working against you, and your class hierarchy is going to waste.  So I'd suggest you simplify.  First, I don't think you need a `BirdTable<T>` or `FishTable<T>`, because the `T` itself parameterizes the table type.  You just need a `TestTable<T> where T : animal`.

Then in a method that merges them, you provide `T` and also `where T : animal` before the body's opening brace.  Since they're parameterized by `T`, it's not possible to mix different table types.

I've taken the liberty of copying and then reworking what you did, below.  I hope you find this helpful for getting insights into using generics.  They do take some time to get used to.  P.S., I've standardized your code to the usual naming conventions and encapsulation approaches in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static string _animal;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TestTable<Bird> birds1 = new TestTable<Bird>();
        birds1.Rows.Add(new Bird());
        birds1.Rows.Add(new Bird());

        TestTable<Bird> birds2 = new TestTable<Bird>();
        birds2.Rows.Add(new Bird());
        birds2.Rows.Add(new Bird());

        TestTable<Bird> allBirds = MergeTestTables<Bird>(birds1, birds2);

        int howManyBirds = allBirds.Rows.Count;

        Console.WriteLine($"There are { howManyBirds } { _animal }s.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static TestTable<T> MergeTestTables<T>(params TestTable<T>[] tables) where T : Animal {
        TestTable<T> merged = new TestTable<T>();

        _animal = typeof(T).Name;
        _animal = _animal.ToLower();

        foreach (TestTable<T> table in tables) {
                foreach (T row in table.Rows) {
                    merged.Rows.Add(row);
                }
        }

        return merged;
    }

    public class TestTable<T> where T : Animal
    {
        public List<T> Rows { get; set; } = new List<T>();
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public int EyeCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bird : Animal
    {
        public int FeatherCount { get; set; }
        public bool CanFly { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fish : Animal
    {
        public int NumberOfFins { get; set; }
        public bool Depth { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. Even though I failed to provide all the code (it was late) your response was perfect.The answer is always so simple when you see it ... yet I got myself all twisted up. Thanks you again!

Comment: Glad I could help.  But it took me a while to get these right, don't sweat it (if you are sweating it).  I don't mean to discourage you from interfaces or class families, by the way, they just weren't mixing well with your generics.